# How to install "Powershell" on freebsd?

Tags: powershell, freebsd, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to install **powershell** on **FreeBSD**,but I couldn't find any **powershell library** for **FreeBSD**.

Comment: See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/1948 - there is no .Net core for FreeBSD so there can't be a PowerShell for it. It was discussed whether the MacOS package would work, and the issue was closed because the originator didn't respond...

Answer (score 4):

Powershell is available for Linux (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/blog/powershell-is-open-sourced-and-is-available-on-linux/), but apparently not (yet) for BSD (https://wiki.freebsd.org/WantedPorts).